# Visual Studio 2012 C# solution, parallel build race condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2012 C# solution that contains around 15 `.csproj` projects.

Each project makes use of a common `foo/bar.cs` file that is generated prior to launching build.

I tried various approaches:

- pre build events
- customizing MSBuild's `BeforeBuild` target

Building each project individually works fine. But as soon as I use "Build Solution", I'm facing a race condition: of of the targets tries to compile `foo/bar.cs` while it's being recreated by another target.

At that point, I realized using "Build Solution" spawns one `MSBuild.exe` process per project in the solution. I think that renders void my attempts to generate `foo/bar.cs` once and for all before starting building projects.

Maybe I overlooked something? Is there an approach that would achieve "generate `foo/bar.cs` before building all?

Comment: Maybe put the file in a single common library project, and have the 15 projects reference that library? That way you only need to include that generate command on your library project.

Comment: I'd make a project whose output is foo/bar.cs, then make the other projects dependent on that project...or make it into a library (since that looks likes semantically what you are trying to do anyway).

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than "put that in a library" unfortunately. Having another project that does nothing but a custom `Build` target is tempting. I'll follow up on that

Comment: This limitation in VS well and truly sucks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadScienceDreams suggested, I created a separate project which other projects depend on.

And I edited the `.csproj` file to import `$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets`
instead of `$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

Then I rewrote the `Build` target in terms of `Exec` task.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sucky way to fix it.

```
msbuild myproject.proj /maxcpucount:1
```

Comment: which you can't do from within the IDE without changing global settings every time you want to use that particular `sln`

Answer (score 0):

```text
before.<SolutionName>.sln.targets
```

placed next to sln file, will be executed before all csproj, this works in msbuild but not in Visual Studio.